# .scrollTop - keep scrolling down each time a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using jQuery and the scrollTo function, is it possible to scroll a certain amount of pixels each time you press a button?

I can already scroll a set amount from the top each time the button is pressed, however I want to keep scrolling everytime the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#theButton').on('click', function()
{
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: Math.abs( $('html').offset().top ) + 20
    }, 500);
});
```

**Note:** If you're using jQuery < 1.7, use `.bind` instead of `.on`.

You should also cache those selectors...

Comment: Hi Joseph, this works, but only once when the button is pressed. It does not keep scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMWindow#scrollBy%28%29) instead of [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMWindow#scrollTo%28%29).